# Filter the list of an array by specific types in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

```html
Raj:merman: 10:49 PM
{
  "statusType":"success",
  "statusMsg":{
     "approvals":{
        "inProgress":[
           {
              "projectStatus":"Pending Decision",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-05-24 09:41:36",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "projectName":"Mobile Test - Jack - POR 1",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23351
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Pending Decision",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO,NNOWR",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-07-31 15:04:30",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "projectName":"TEST POR CAHNGE REQ",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":24324
           }
        ],
        "draft":[
        ],
        "completed":[
           {
              "projectStatus":"Declined",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO,NHQIR",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-07-08 12:27:16",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"POR : mobile 1:1 testing 01",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"07/08/2019",
              "requestorName":"Upadhyay,Viraj",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23918
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Completed",
              "pcbu":"NMTNR,NKSMO",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-05-14 14:35:41",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"Mobile Test - POR - 2",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"05/14/2019",
              "requestorName":"Inphouva,April",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23258
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Declined",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-07-17 14:20:27",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"por mobile test",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"07/17/2019",
              "requestorName":"Upadhyay,Viraj",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":24081
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Declined",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO,NNCNV",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-05-14 13:49:31",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"Mobile Test - POR 1",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"05/14/2019",
              "requestorName":"Inphouva,April",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23254
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Completed",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-06-28 08:32:42",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"Mobile Test - POR - F",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"06/28/2019",
              "requestorName":"Inphouva,April",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23871
           }
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

[image: JSON Response]

[image: image of the options showing multiple times]

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" >
<h3 class="projectFont no-margin queueStyling">Queue</h3>
<div class=" nopadding-bottom">
<div class="row">
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group margin-bottom-10" style="width: 100%;">
   <div class="input-group input-transparent-field" style="width: 25%;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 1%;
      margin-left: 4%;">
      <label for="search-" class="sr-only"> Search</label>
      <input type="text" id="requestInfoSearch" class="workflow-search-transparent-field form-control  border-none" placeholder="Search by Name or Requestor !!!!!!!" ng-model="workflowQueueSearch">
      <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ng-disabled="true"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
   </div>
   <label for="Type" class="control-label-left typeAllOptionStyling">Type</label>
   <div class="selecteddiv" style="margin-right: 1%;">
      <select ng-model="folderSearchType" name="folderSearchType" ng-options="obj.requestType for obj in inProgressDataList"></select>
   </div>
   <label for="PCBU" class="vz-control-label-left typeAllOptionStyling">PCBU</label>
   <div class="selecteddiv" style="margin-right: 1%;">
      <select ng-model="pcbuSelect" name="pcbuSelect" ng-options="obj.pcbu for obj in inProgressDataList"></select>
   </div>
   <label for="Requestor" class="vz-control-label-left typeAllOptionStyling">Requestor</label>
   <div class="selecteddiv" style="margin-right: 1%;">
      <select ng-model="requestorSelect" name="requestorSelect" ng-options="item for item in toUserList" ></select>
   </div>
   <label for="Status" class="vz-control-label-left typeAllOptionStyling">Status</label>
   <div class="selecteddiv" style="margin-right: 1%;">
      <select ng-model="projectStatusSelect" name="projectStatusSelect" ng-options="obj.projectStatus for obj in inProgressDataList"></select>
   </div>
   <button ng-click="clearAll()" style="color: #CD040B;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: nhg-text-bold,arial,sans-serif;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 4px!important;">Clear All</button>
</div>
```

html for the lists:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body noTopBottompadding">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  nopadding" >
<div class="table-responsive workflow-home-table">
<table class="table nomargin priortyStyling" style="border:none">
<thead>
   <th class="searchPointer" ng-click="sortType = 'requestType'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      Request Type
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'requestType' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'requestType' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   </th>
   <th  class="searchPointer"  ng-click="sortType = 'pcbu'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      PCBU
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'pcbu' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'pcbu' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   </th>
   <th></th>
   <th class="searchPointer"  ng-click="sortType = 'projectName'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      Request Name
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'projectName' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'projectName' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   </th>
   <th class="searchPointer"  ng-click="sortType = 'projectStatus'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      Status
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'projectStatus' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'projectStatus' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   </th>
   <th></th>
   <th class="searchPointer"  ng-click="sortType = 'projectId'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      Request ID
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'projectId' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'projectId' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   </th>
   <th  class="searchPointer" ng-click="sortType = 'statusUpdatedDate'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      Date
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'statusUpdatedDate' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'statusUpdatedDate' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   </th>
   <th  class="searchPointer" ng-click="sortType = 'statusUpdatedDate'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      Requestor
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'statusUpdatedDate' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
      <span ng-if="sortType == 'statusUpdatedDate' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
   </th>
</thead>
<tbody class="priortyStyling">
   <tr ng-repeat="inProgressData in inProgressDataList | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:workflowQueueSearch | filter:projectStatusSelect | filter:requestorSelect | filter:folderSearchType | filter:pcbuSelect">
      <td>{{changeRequestType(inProgressData.requestType)}}</td>
      <td>{{inProgressData.pcbu}}</td>
      <td class="priortyStyling"  ng-if="inProgressData.priority == '' || inProgressData.priority == 'NORMAL'">
         <!-- <img src="images/homepage/Medium.png" width="20" height="20" alt="{{inProgressData.priority}}"> -->
      </td>
      <td class="priortyStyling" ng-if="inProgressData.priority == 'HIGH'">
         <img src="images/homepage/High.png" width="13" height="13" alt="{{inProgressData.priority}}">
      </td>
      <td><a href="#" target="_self" ng-click="onWorkFlowHomeSelection(inProgressData,'Inprogress')">{{inProgressData.projectName}}</a></td>
      <td>{{inProgressData.projectStatus}}</td>
      <td>{{inProgressData.projectDispachStatus}}</td>
      <td>{{inProgressData.projectId}}</td>
      <td>{{ formatDateAndTime(inProgressData.statusUpdatedDate) | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a'}} CST</td>
      <td>{{projectData.requestAction.name}}</td>
```

I am trying to filter the list of requests by types,PCBU, requestors, and status, these are just four categories so i made several selects with ng-options but in ng options its showing repeated types as I am getting the lists as dynamics, I am attaching screenshots for both things.

I tried by making lists of types and then give it as options in the ng-options but there are so many types and some types should not be included according to the requests. So can you please tell me how to display options from those specific lists only and then filter the lists according to the options.

I expected the output to that display the options according to whats in the lists only and then refresh the lists according to the selected options from dropdown. Please help, I did some research but struggling with the results.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I read filter && list in the title but the question has no list as a code!

Comment: I am expecting JSON data as a code like: `[{key:"value"},{key:"value"}]` ectc

Comment: How would I extract data from Image and try some code to find out the issue? Images are not good interms of code

Comment: From the JSON I think it is better to have `approvals` as a single array and have a `status` key as `inProgress`, 'draft` etc. Then you can easily filter the data.

Comment: I want to filter the displayed elements of $scope.inprogressdatalist array. The products is an array of objects, containing few elements with their own type: pcbu or request status. I just want to filter the array if user clicks on the select option pcbu or type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the UI you can filter the data if it is a single array in the http response. Sample input and output is given. If this is not what you are looking for kindly provide more information.

```js
var approvals = [
  {
              "projectStatus":"Pending Decision",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-05-24 09:41:36",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "projectName":"Mobile Test - Jack - POR 1",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23351,
        "status": "inProgress"
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Pending Decision",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO,NNOWR",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-07-31 15:04:30",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "projectName":"TEST POR CAHNGE REQ",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":24324,
        "status": "inProgress"
           },{
              "projectStatus":"Declined",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO,NHQIR",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-07-08 12:27:16",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"POR : mobile 1:1 testing 01",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"07/08/2019",
              "requestorName":"Upadhyay,Viraj",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23918,
        "status": "completed"
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Completed",
              "pcbu":"NMTNR,NKSMO",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-05-14 14:35:41",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"Mobile Test - POR - 2",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"05/14/2019",
              "requestorName":"Inphouva,April",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23258,
        "status": "completed"
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Declined",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-07-17 14:20:27",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"por mobile test",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"07/17/2019",
              "requestorName":"Upadhyay,Viraj",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":24081,
        "status": "completed"
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Declined",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO,NNCNV",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-05-14 13:49:31",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"Mobile Test - POR 1",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"05/14/2019",
              "requestorName":"Inphouva,April",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23254,
        "status": "completed"
           },
           {
              "projectStatus":"Completed",
              "pcbu":"NKSMO",
              "statusUpdatedDate":"2019-06-28 08:32:42",
              "requestType":"PORCHNGEREQ",
              "folderStatus":false,
              "requestedAmount":0,
              "projectName":"Mobile Test - POR - F",
              "completeUpdatedDate":"06/28/2019",
              "requestorName":"Inphouva,April",
              "priority":"NORMAL",
              "projectId":23871,
        "status": "completed"
           }
  ];
const completed  = approvals.filter(approval => approval.status == "completed");
const inProgress = approvals.filter(approval => approval.status == "inProgress");
const projectStatusPendingDecision = approvals.filter(approval => approval.projectStatus == "Pending Decision");
console.log("Completed items");
console.log(completed);
console.log("<======================================>");
console.log("In Progress items");

console.log(inProgress);
console.log("<======================================>");
console.log("project Status Pending Decision items");


console.log(projectStatusPendingDecision);
```

Comment: Hi @krishnadas This does not solve problem please update the answer if you can! I want to filter the displayed elements of $scope.inprogressdatalist array. The products is an array of objects, containing few elements with their own type: pcbu or request status. I just want to filter the array if user clicks on the select option pcbu or type.